# Open Popup in checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, knockoutjs

I need to create a popup for coupon code in checkout page..

**In discount.js:**

```
 showPopup: function () {
            alert("popup");

            var couponcodepopup = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: false,
                title: "Naa",
                modalClass: "popup-center",
                clickableOverlay: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            };
            modal(couponcodepopup, $('.payment-option-inner'));            
            $('.payment-option-inner').modal('openModal');
        },
```

**In discount.html**

```
 <div class="payment-option-title field choice" data-role="title" data-bind="click: showPopup()">
        <span class="action action-toggle" id="block-discount-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'Apply Discount Code'--><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-option-content" data-role="content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <form class="form form-discount" id="discount-form">
            <div class="payment-option-inner">
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label" for="discount-code">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Enter discount code'"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input-text"
                               type="text"
                               id="discount-code"
                               name="discount_code"
                               data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                               data-bind="value: couponCode, attr:{placeholder: $t('Enter discount code')} " />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <!-- ko ifnot: isApplied() -->
                    <button class="action action-apply" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Apply Discount'), click: apply">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Apply Discount'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: isApplied() -->
                    <button class="action action-cancel" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Cancel'), click: cancel">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Cancel coupon'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <div id="login-msg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I can get the popup without loading any content..
[image]

If any one knows ...Guide me..

Thanks.